# XP Pro SP3 unresponsive requires power down

Tags: windows-xp, anti-virus, malware

New to serverfault, but searched google and the forums here and haven't found anything regarding my issue.

I have two laptops in my network that are displaying similar issues. They are from different manufactures so it can't be hardware model related I don't think. Both machines will be running perfectly then they will lockup, but the mouse will be responsive. I am unable to ctrl-alt-delete or actually click anything. Powering down the machine gets everything back to 'normal'. I have checked the event application and system log without anything glaring standing out at me. I have also run a full a/v scan with NOD32 and run a malwarebytes scan, both come up negative.

Both machines are running sp3 and to date on windows update.

Has anyone ever seen this before. I know that it's vague and I really don't want to re image the machines if i don't know whats causing it.

Thanks.

-B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found out that the issue was a faulty driver for a sprint evdo card. removed the driver and issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You can try running process explorer from sysinternals and have that monitoring in the background, see what "pops up" when it locks up.

You're saying the interface will update, but just the keyboard is unresponsive? i.e., if you have task manager running, it will keep updating but you can't click on anything?

Or do you mean you have external keyboard and mouse plugged in and see this happen?

Are there any events that correlate at all...certain applications are running, certain time of day it happens, etc?

Have you reseated the memory in them?

What about a USB keyboard, if you're not using one? Does anything happen when you plug that in, so as to narrow down if you have a loose connector for the internal keyboard?

Comment: machine will be frozen in whatever state it's in usually ms word running or just the desktop is displayed. mouse cursor still moves but anything else is unresponsive.

i'll try reseating the memory.

Comment: Hmm...sometimes I've tried using a process monitor to see what last appears just before a lockup on the program as taking up CPU/disk access at the time of lockup in case it's a particular program causing the issue. It sounds almost like it's processor/memory seating or a driver issue from the description.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen identical symptoms with an Intel 910/915 laptop video adapter; the driver gets locked into an infinite loop in some cases.  I don't think this is your issue however, as it only occurred when running OpenGL accelerated software and it left an entry in the event log.

Comment: I found this on one of the machines in the event viewer

A driver packet received from the I/O subsystem was invalid.  The data is the packet.

think it's as easy as updating the drive?

Comment: It could be that simple; definitely worth a try anyway.